# How to add access control to tab

Tags: joomla-3.x, access

I have component and into this component customly add tab with some functionality. Now I want that only some group of users can see that tab.

How can I add some code to give access to only group that I want?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this extension to enable disable menu extension ir content for each user ir group user.

http://www.pages-and-items.com/extensions/user-private-page

Answer (score 0):

Goto this link it will helps you (https://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Access_Control_List_Tutorial) (https://docs.joomla.org/User_Group_Access_levels_explained_in_simple_terms)

Comment: Thank for your answer but as i say below tab added customly and need add some code to tab code for access.